# C - How do I get the token before the one I'm currently in?

Tags: c, token

I'm trying to return to the console in C the token that is before the one I'm currently in into a file. The tokens get separated by delimiters. Do I need to implement some kind of counter?

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char line [1000];
    char *delimeters = ".,; \t\n";
    FILE *input = fopen (argv[2], "r");

    while(fgets(line,1000,input) != NULL)
    {
        char *word = strtok(line, delimeters);

        while(word != NULL)
        {
            if(word != NULL && strcmp(word,"(") == 0)
            {
                printf("Enters IF 3\n");
                char *method_name = strtok(NULL, delimeters); //NEED BEFORE WORD
                printf ("Method %s\n", method_name);
            }
```

Comment: Can't you just store previous one in a `char *prev` ?

Comment: And how do I write that down? Because at the time I enter the if statement I am already in the next one.

Is like this "Something ( )" I get printed out the ")" and I want "Something".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, rather than look for the previous token after, I have to look for something before in the if statement. It's somehow a tricky question anyway.

Example: `Method Return_type Something ();`

Rather than looking for `(` I have to look for `Method` and then jump to `Something` with `strtok`.